# Routing traffic back and forth through a mac mini server with 2 network interfaces

Tags: networking, routing, mac-osx

I have my office network that looks like this:

[image: networking scheme]

My office network looks like this:

- the office network (wifi and wired) has the subnetwork `192.168.88.0`.
- I and I have some server machines on the subnetwork `192.168.2.0` (NODE_1,.... NODE_10).
- I have a machine (is a MacMini) with 2 subnetwork interfaces that acts as:

  - the gateway for all machines in subnetwork  `192.168.2.0`.
  - exposes a VPN service (the Mac server app default one)
  - and provides extra services, such as a DNS)

The MacMini configuration is my big trouble. This is how it looks like.

**Ethernet interface en0**

- address: `192.168.88.10`
- netmask: `255.255.255.0`
- gateway: `192.168.88.1`

**Ethernet interface en2**

- address: `192.168.2.1`
- netmask: `255.255.255.0`
- gateway: `192.168.88.10`

I need routing from machines in `192.168.88.0` to those in `192.168.2.0`.

To do so I have activated the ***"Internet sharing"*** feature of the MacOs: actually I do not know what happens under the hood, but the machines **NODE_1** ...**NODE_10** go to internet.

Then, when I'm connected to the office network, so that I get an IP such as: `192.168.88.33` I add a routing rule such as:

```
 sudo route -n add 192.168.2.0/24 -gateway 192.168.88.10
```

So far so good: everything works fine!!!!!

The big problem is when I connect through the VPN.

### VPN Connection

I connect successfully to the VPN exposed at: `192.168.88.10`, then I add the routing rule.

```
 sudo route -n add 192.168.2.0/24 -gateway 192.168.88.10
```

I'm not able to reach the machines in subnet `192.168.2.0`.

Sniffing the packets I see that the packets follow the hops:

1. -> 192.168.88.10
2. -> 192.168.2.1
3. -> 192.168.2.110
4. <- 192.168.2.1
5. <- 192.168.88.1

The packet goes to the gateway `192.168.88.1` instead of the `192.168.88.10`. Looking into the MacMini routing tables I see:

```
192.168.88.202     192.168.88.10      UH              2       93    ppp1
192.168.88.202     40:6c:8f:3:d5:e7   UHLS2           0        0     en0
```

`40:6c:8f:3:d5:e7` is the mac address of `192.168.88.1`.

I would like to change the routing without using the **internet sharing** in order to allow internet access for `192.168.2.0`, and cover both the VPN and local scenario, but I don't know the steps I need to do, and how to hand write the rules.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What OS is your server running?

Comment: the NODE_1 ... NODE_10 are Linux while the SERVER is a MacMini running El Capitan.

Comment: So everything seems great ok fine I get it until you add a route after you connect to the VPN.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish or fix by doing that?  Are you trying to make it so 192.168.88.0/24 can reach 192.168.2.0/24? (because...if so...,we can probably help)